# C++: references and factories

Tags: c++, c++11

I have something like this:

```
struct D {
    virtual void operator() {...};
}
struct D1 : public D {
    virtual void operator() {...};
}
struct D2 : public D {
    virtual void operator() {...};
}

void foo(D &d) {...};
```

And so this is fine, and nicely controls the life cycle of my D's:

```
foo(D());
foo(D1());
foo(D2());
```

But I choose my D variant in multiple places, so I want a simple factory:

```
const D& make_D()
{
    // BAD, returning reference to temporary
    if(is_tuesday())
        return D1();
    return D2();
}
```

Instead of returning a reference to a temporary, I could return an object, but then I slice to the base class.  Alternatively, I could return a pointer from my factory, but then the client has to delete it.  Other, more complicated, solutions also impose more load on the client.

Is there a way to write something like

```
D& d = make_D();
foo(d);
```

(or even `foo(make_D())`)?  The goal is to wrap the complexity in the various D definitions and in `make_D()` so that the functions like `foo()` and those who call those functions needn't worry about it.

Comment: Note: `foo(D())` will not compile (not under a conforming compiler. Even VS emits a warning about non-standard behavior), because a temporary cannot be bound to a non-const l-value reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way is to either return a pointer or a smart pointer.

The downside of using a pointer is letting the user manage its memory.

If you return a smart pointer, this is no longer an issue.

```
const SmartPtr<D> make_D()
{
    if(is_tuesday())
        return SmartPtr(new D1());
    return SmartPtr(new D2());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, that is not possible.

Usually, what I do is to use `std::unique_ptr` (sometimes `std::shared_ptr`, when it is not possible to use `std::unique_ptr`) :

```
typedef std::unique_ptr< D > Dptr;
Dptr make_D()
{
    Dptr p( nulptr );

    if(is_tuesday())
        p.reset( new D1 );
    else
        p.reset( new D2 );

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not too sure I understand.  The code you've listed isn't
legal, and won't compile.  Are you sure that it isn't:

```
struct D
{
    virtual void operator()() const { /* ... */ }
};
```

and:

```
void foo( D const& d ) { /* ... */ }
```

invocation, or is mutable?  (Presumably not, since you don't pass in any
arguments, and you throw away the object after use.)  If not, then you
can simply return references to static instances.  This is the usual
solution I use.  Otherwise, it's possible to make a copyable object
behave polymorphicly, using the letter envelop idiom, but it's a bit
of work, and has significant runtime overhead, since it normally
requires cloning of the actual object for each copy.